# Why can't I update my variables from my Model in my Controller using C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, getter-setter

I'm trying to run an update process in my Controller and in doing so trying to access values from my Model, this is the code in my Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public void updateNewGroup(int id)
    {
        int incomingID = id;
        TaskViewModel model = new TaskViewModel();                       
        model.groupIdx.Add(id);            
    }
```

This is how I've set up my variable in my Model

```
    public List<int> groupIdx { get; set; }
```

When the code runs and it attempts to update groupIdx list I get an error 'NullReferenceException unhandled by user' what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which line do you get the NullReferenceException ?

Comment: Because `groupIdx` is `null`. You need to initialize it - `model.groupIdx = new List<int>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see - you're not initializing `model.groupIdx` thus it remains `null` - that's why you're getting `NullReferenceException`

It should be something like

```
TaskViewModel model = new TaskViewModel();                       
model.groupIdx = new List<int>();
model.groupIdx.Add(id);
```

Comment: Both answers were correct, thank you. The only other problem is that each time the updateNewGroup method is called groupIdx is always null and never retains it's value. How do I get it to persist?

Comment: @user616076 of course `groupIdx` is null each time you're calling `updateNewGroup` because you're creating new model each time in the very beginning of this method. If you need to somehow store this `groupIdx` - it can be done by variable ways. You can store it in DB, some static field  or something else - it's a broad question and it's hard to say more without knowing your application architecture and goals.

Answer (score 0):

Your groupIdx is still null, it's uninitialized. Either add a constructor to the Model where you initialize it or set it when you create the object.

```
model.groupIdx = new List<int>();
```